# Fuji X-Pro2 with 18-135 lens, OVP usability

Tags: fujifilm, fujifilm-xpro1

I would like to buy an X-Pro2 with an 18-135 zoom lens. How much does the lens size affect the usability of OVP? How much do you lose on the right side of the viewfinder?

Answer (score 1):

There is a huge impact and makes the OVF mode rather hard to use. Luckily, the EVF mode is really fantastic.

The lens barrel will be visible on the lower right of the OVF and crops a significant portion which gets bigger as you zoom in. The X-Pro2 in turn will shrink the bright lines to indicate the coverage of the focal-length but it very quickly becomes too small to properly frame your subject.